# Best way using attachBaseContext for all Activities without inheritance

Tags: android, inheritance, android-activity, composition

I'm want to use a SDK that is telling me to override the `attachBaseContext` of all activities or create a `BaseActivity`

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
       super.attachBaseContext(LibraryX.wrap(newBase));
    }
}
```

But I don't want to use inheritance for all my activities. We are moving away from having a BaseActivity. I looked around and searched for something that could help me implement this differently.

Sadly `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` isnt providing a `attachBaseContext` method. Otherwise I was done.

Is this a nice way to do this without using inheritance?

Comment: No, cause you have to call the `super` method which can be done only through inheritance.

Comment: Well, you wana call base class method when derived class is called with the same method ... so, answer is obvious ... you can only do by inheritance ... what is wrong with `BaseActivity` ?

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no way of doing that without inheritance since you absolutely must call the super method and there is no API to access that method externally (like a listener)